# What should I consider in analyzing test results from k6 cloud?

Tags: javascript, load, performance-testing, load-testing, k6

I am new to k6. I just created a script for a single scenario then I ran it locally via Visual Studio Code in my computer and I integrated the results in k6 cloud using –out cloud command in terminal upon execution.

My script was configured to run 170 users under 5 minutes. I also added some thresholds. Please see below script option:

```
export const options = {
ext: {
    loadimpact: {
        projectID: #####,
        // Test runs with the same name groups test runs together
        name: "#######",

        distribution: {
            "amazon:sg:singapore": {
                loadZone: "amazon:sg:singapore",
                percent: 100,
            },
        },

    }
}, stages: [
    { duration: "1m", target: 170 },
    { duration: "3m", target: 170 },
    { duration: "1m", target: 0 },
],

thresholds: {
    http_req_failed: ['rate<0.01'], 
    http_req_duration: ['p(99)<=3000', 'p(95)<=3000', 'avg <= 3000'], 
    
},};
```

After generating the test results in the cloud, I am not sure what actual/main Response Time or other data results I should consider.

As per requirement, the Expected KPI (During Peak Load) of that scenario is less than or equal to 3 seconds. If it is <= 3 seconds…then it is PASSED. If it is greater than 3 seconds…then is FAILED.

What specific part of the different displayed test data results in K6 cloud should I refer/consider to know if it is passed or failed as per requirement? Please see below images.

[Sample K6 Cloud Data Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZtJJ.png)

[Test Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4C2H.jpg)

Any help or discussion means a lot to me. Appreciate the help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here are response times metrics:

[image]

- `MIN` and `MAX` are self-explanatory
- `AVG` is [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of all requests response times (sum of all response times divided by their count)
- `STDDEV` is [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), statistical measure showing how different are response times from each other, lower deviation means that you're getting more or less the same response times, higher deviation means that they are distributed, certain requests have lower response times, certain requests higher
- `P95` and `P99` are [Percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) showing response time which 95% and 99% of users are getting correspondingly, I would recommend sticking to one of those, i.e. 99% would be a good choice.

As none of response times (including maximum) doesn't exceed 3 seconds I would consider the test as successful.

More information: [Understanding Your Reports: Part 3 - Key Statistics Performance Testers Need to Understand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-3-key-statistics-performance-testers-need-understand)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Just to confirm, what all I need is to look or base my result (whether passed or failed) from the displayed data of min, max, avg, stddev, and p99/p95 (considered pass if they are below 3 seconds as per requirement).

If so, may I know the purpose of the "Average Response Time" displayed under Performance Overview Panel in k6 Cloud? (113ms based from the attached image). Should I just DISREGARD it and merely focus only on the metrics you've mentioned to know if pass or fail? 

Sorry for the silly question. I'm really new here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have 2 requests: first one has response time of 1 second, second one has response time of 5 seconds, average response time is 3 seconds. Would you consider this test passed or failed?

Comment: Hmm good point! Answering your question, I think it should be considered as failed. Each endpoints' response time of the scenario should be taken into consideration also, not only the average response time as a whole scenario. So I should always base it then to the response time metrics (min,max,p95,p99...etc.) and not to the displayed average time in performance overview panel! Thanks a lot for these insights!! Big help!